# PHP mod_rewrite & .htaccess for clean URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite the following 3 URLs to translate into the correct pages.

highscore.php is in my main directory

```
    www.domain.com/clan/
    www.domain.com/highscore.php

    www.domain.com/clan/Halos
    www.domain.com/highscore.php?clan=Halos

    www.domain.com/clan/Halos/Cooking
    www.domain.com/highscore.php?clan=Halos&view=Cooking
```

---

I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^clan/([^/]*)$ /highscore.php?clan=$1&view=$2 [L]
```

---

This successfully maps the following URL:

```
    www.domain.com/clan/Halos
```

to

```
    www.domain.com/highscore.php?clan=Halos
```

---

The following URL goes to the highscore.php page with a null 'clan' parameter

```
    www.domain.com/clan/
```

is mapping to

```
    www.domain.com/highscore.php?clan=
```

I'm trying to get it to map to

```
    www.domain.com/highscore.php
```

---

When I go to

```
    www.domain.com/clan/Halos/Cooking
```

It only recognizes the first parameter 'Halos' and not the second one 'Cooking' ? It takes me to:

```
    www.domain.com/highscore.php?clan=Halos
```

Very confused, I need some direction to what I'm doing right and/or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

#Rewrite base path
RewriteRule ^clan/$ /highscore.php [L]
#Rewrite clan path
RewriteRule ^clan/([^/]*)$ /highscore.php?clan=$1 [L]
#Rewrite view path
RewriteRule ^clan/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /highscore.php?clan=$1&view=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule doesn't have a second extracted portion in the expression, so only one parameter is extracted. Here's how you would extract a second parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^clan/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /highscore.php?clan=$1&view=$2 [L]
```

Now you're extracting two parts here (denoted by the brackets).